# In busboy.event(finish) I can't get file.pipe.object result

Tags: node.js, busboy

For example：
1. Test1.txt Its base64：VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0MS4=
2. Test2.txt Its base64：VGhpcyBpcyBUZXN0Mi4=

My code:

```
var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
var base64data = [];
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    var output = stream.PassThrough();
    var chunk = [];
    console.log('File: ' + filename + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
    file.pipe(base64.encode()).pipe(output);
    output.on('data', function(data) {
        chunk.push(data);
        console.log('Chunk: ' + chunk);
    });
    output.on('end', function(){
        base64data.push(Buffer.concat(chunk));
        console.log('Data1: ' + base64data);
    });
}).on('finish', function(){
    console.log('Data2: ' + base64data);
})
```

output:

```
File: Test1.txt, mimetype: text/plain
File: Test2.txt, mimetype: text/plain
Chunk: VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0
Chunk: VGhpcyBpcyBUZXN0
Chunk: VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0,MS4=
Chunk: VGhpcyBpcyBUZXN0,Mi4=
Data2:
Data1: VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0MS4=
Data1: VGhpcyBpcyB0ZXN0MS4=,VGhpcyBpcyBUZXN0Mi4=
```

Why is Data2 empty? How do I modify this code? Please Help! Thanks~

I tried to use Buffer.toString('base64') in file.event(data), but it can only convert text content, pictures can not be converted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need those extra streams. The problem though is that the extra streams' `end` events are emitted on the next tick (thus, after busboy's `finish` event).

You should be able to simplify your code to this:

```
var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
var base64data = [];
busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
  console.log('File: ' + filename + ', mimetype: ' + mimetype);
  var buffer = '';
  file.setEncoding('base64');
  file.on('data', function(data) {
    // `data` is now a base64-encoded chunk of file data
    buffer += data;
  }).on('end', function() {
    base64data.push(buffer);
  });
}).on('finish', function(){
  console.log('Data2: ' + base64data);
})
```